# When is "_." used in python

Tags: python

Sometimes I have seen people using the expression `_.` in python code. 
For example,

```
_.objectName = 23
```

Can someone help me out what exactly does "_." mean? 
Can someone give me more examples of this type with explanation?

Comment: By code, do you mean you've seen it on an interpreter, a Read Eval Print Loop (`>>> `)?

Answer (score 6):

`_` is a valid variable name in python (as well as most other languages.) It's conventionally used to store throw-away values you don't care about. Using the variable, as in your example, is bad form.

Comment: If it's a throwaway value, why is a method being called on it?

Comment: @AaronHall that is why he said it was bad form

Comment: @cmd See another common usage in my answer, I think that would be much more likely.

Comment: @AaronHall which is not valid because he said it was in python code.

Comment: So on a REPL, it's no longer code? I doubt the OP had that intention.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, it's likely that you've seen that in an interpreter, where it typically aliases the last returned value.

For example:

```
>>> foo = 'bar'
>>> foo
'bar'
>>> _
'bar'
>>> _.upper()
'BAR'
```

It is sometimes used as a throwaway, e.g. make a list of ten items unrelated to range:

```
['foo' for _ in range(10)]
```

But in this case, there would be no reason to call a method or reference an attribute on it, so I think the usage you've seen is more likely attributed to interpreter use. If you see this in scripts, that would be bad form, but I've rarely seen that.